# Length Contraction of the Schwarzschild Radius

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

I'm having trouble understanding the flaw in the following argument regarding the length contraction of the Schwarzschild radius in the frame of observers on a collapsing shell.  Is there something fundamental that I'm misinterpreting in this argument?

Consider a spherically symmetric shell collapsing toward its Schwarzschild radius.  At the beginning of collapse, the radius of the shell is greater than the Schwarzschild radius and we place two rods inside the shell whose rest lengths are the Schwarzschild radius of the shell with one end of each rod placed at the center of the shell.  Let us place two observers, Alice and Bob, on opposite sides of the shell in free fall with it as depicted in the following figure:

[image]

According to Birkhoff's theorem, the spacetime inside the collapsing shell in Minkowskian and the rods are at rest relative to the collapsing shell.  As the shell collapses, the velocities of both Alice and Bob will increase relative to the rods.  But in the frame of Alice or Bob, it is the rods that are moving toward them.  Therefore, the rods will become increasingly length contracted in both Alice and Bob's frames as the shell collapses due to the relative velocities between the rods and the observers.  We know that as the shell approaches its Schwarzschild radius, this relative velocity will approach the speed of light and the lengths of the rods in Alice and Bob's frames will contract to zero length as they reach the horizon.

Therefore, when the shell reaches the Schwarzschild radius, the space between Bob and Alice as observed by Alice and Bob will be relativistically contracted to zero and in their frames, and they will be coincident.  What this tells us is that in the frame of the material falling to form a Black Hole, there is no spacetime beyond the Schwarzschild radius.  In that frame, when the material reaches the Schwarzschild radius, then the material has been compressed to a point and there is nowhere else to fall.  Therefore, in the freefalling frame, Black Holes have no interior.  The Schwarzschild radius as viewed by an infinite observer corresponds to zero radius in the frame of free falling particles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139899/discussion-on-question-by-chris-laforet-length-contraction-of-the-schwarzschild).